# How to create/save files within a loop in a function?

Tags: python, function, loops, output

How can I save/create a file within a loop in a function? In the following example I want to run a function which prints a message and saves a file with the message in every iteration. However, it prints the messages but only saves the very last file (10). I guess it doesn’t look so advisable. The point is that my real function is a comprehensive water flow model that produces several data sets. In the case that somebody wants to see or use all the data of every time step, I want to avoid a clogging of the memory by writing everything to the disk. I prefer losing CPU performance to a clogged memory.

```
  def worldloop(message='hello world',no=10):
      import numpy as np
      fname_template='/home/blubb/Desktop/blaa{cap}'
      for i in range(no):
          cap=no
          np.save(fname_template.format(cap=cap) , message )
          print message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistake `cap=no` where `no == 10` just change it to `cap=i` or use `i`:

```
def worldloop(message='hello world',no=10):
      import numpy as np
      fname_template='/home/blubb/Desktop/blaa{cap}'
      for i in range(no):
          np.save(fname_template.format(cap=i) , message )
          print message
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `cap = no` every iteration, then use `cap` as file name, so you are overwriting the same file every time.

Delete `cap = no` and change `np.save(fname_template.format(cap=cap) , message )` to `np.save(fname_template.format(cap=i) , message )`